# tables with overhead

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know whether there is any query to find table names with overhead.

This query is particular to MySQL Database, and I believe that those who work on MySQL will be knowing what overhead to a table is.

Comment: "overhead" is a vague term, and doesn't register to me as a MySQL keyword.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565997/in-mysql-what-does-overhead-mean-what-is-bad-about-it-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: @OMG Ponies: indeed, but in some unknown reason some people call fragmented data files as "overheaded" :-S

Comment: @zerkms: thanks for the link, but I need to find those tables which have overhead or fragmented data file. How can I achieve this using a query?

Comment: @I-M-JM: the good practice is to schedule optimize command execution and optimize periodically all tables.

Comment: @zerkms: well that's what I have implemented, but still need this option.

Comment: @I-M-JM: you have done it in right way. I'm not sure it can even be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think schedule optimization is only way available.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

phpmyadmin - select database - go to bottom of screen - click "Check tables having overhead" It selects tables with overhead.