# Mysql Phpmyadmin overhead

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In MySQL what does “Overhead” mean, what is bad about it, and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565997/in-mysql-what-does-overhead-mean-what-is-bad-about-it-and-how-to-fix-it)

[image]

Hi experts,

As you can see there is an overhead warning.The table is actually contain no data at all..

I keep getting this warning so often..I wonder is mysql really overhead or it just phpMyadmin thinggy..

Sure when i optimize the table, the overhead warning is gone..But after some insertion and deletion (u know during develope some feature), the overhead warning will show up again.

Im really curious why is this happening..Any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: i'm not an expert on the subject, but i think that overhead comes from things like indexes, or maybe cached or outdated data. i wouldn't worry about it too much; you can optimize your table once in awhile or maybe set up a cron.

Comment: @Mark is there any performance impact sir?

Comment: Are we seriously talking about the performance impact of *18 bytes*?

Comment: @DCoder im really sucky at database, yeah my question might look silly..im taking an effort to learn as much as i can about mysql..thx for ur input

Comment: phpmyadmin is likely doing a comparison between your data usage and your overhead, and right now it thinks that the table is 100% overhead. It's technically correct, since it's empty, but that doesn't mean that it's anything to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPmyAdmin is likely doing a comparison between your data usage and your overhead, and right now it thinks that the table is 100% overhead. It's technically correct, since it's empty, but that doesn't mean that it's anything to worry about.